# recreate array with all items but the last

Tags: json, jq

Given the following:

**Input:**

```
[
  [
    {
      "type": "strip",
      "output": "debian-7-x86_64-strip"
    },
    {
      "type": "compress",
      "output": "debian-7-x86_64-compress"
    },
    {
      "type": "full",
      "output": "debian-7-x86_64"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "type": "strip",
      "output": "debian-8-strip"
    },
    {
      "type": "compress",
      "output": "debian-8-compress"
    }
  ]
]
```

How to recreate the array with the last object item (from each sub-array) removed?

**Desired Output:**

```
[
  [
    {
      "type": "strip",
      "output": "debian-7-x86_64-strip"
    },
    {
      "type": "compress",
      "output": "debian-7-x86_64-compress"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "type": "strip",
      "output": "debian-8-strip"
    }
  ]
]
```

I've tried using things like `... |= .[:-1]` and `...[to_entries | last]`, and `... | select(last|not)` but I'm having no success.

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.[][0:-1]` gets you far, just missing the surrounding array in the output.

EDIT: `[.[][:-1]]` should do it.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks.

Comment: Or just: `.[:-1]`